# Need to Disable a column in a Data Grid View in Winform

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have a data grid view ( say 5 columns ) . User has the option to disable/enable 1 particular column of the data table (using radio buttons). So How should I go about doing it?

When I select to disable the column, I need to make it non editable, change the color of the column so that user can understand that the column is disabled and any other suggestion are also welcome.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Set the column's ReadOnly property to true to make it non-editable.  And alter its DefaultCellStyle.BackColor (and/or ForeColor) to make it obvious to the user.

Answer (score 1):

I also came across the same problem,and its sol. for me is:

```
 int n = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView3.Rows.Count.ToString());
         for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
         {
             dataGridView3.Rows[i].Cells[0].ReadOnly = true;
         }
```

And it really worked for me.Works good when you are not going to declare columns name in datagridview and bringing it from any database.

Answer (score -1):

Your GridView control exposes the [Columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridview.columns%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) property. Through [these objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridviewcolumn%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you can set properties (including visibility) for the individual columns. Example:

```
GridView.Columns[6].visible=false;
```